# VS 2019 - run project as application inside web site

Tags: iis, azure-active-directory, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to find a way to test something specific. I am having an issue with a web application to where it redirects to the website and not the web application after being published and deployed to IIS. So to debug the issue i need to set up Visual Studio to have the same structure as IIS. I am integrating with AzureAD and after the login to Azure redirects to the web app, the web app then redirects again. So after AzureAD login, i am at the right URL, but then for some reason get redirected again. So i need to debug.

Example of the issue:

1. Go to website: https://myurl.com/webApp1/
2. push button to log in to AzureAD.
3. redirects to MS Azure login screen.
4. after successful login to Azure, redirects back to site: https://myurl.com/webApp1/
5. web app then redirects to website with no app name: https://myurl.com/

Running the site through VS 2019, it is always: https://localhost/
so the issue doesn't happen because it is ok if the site redirects to https://localhost/ at any point.

My question is if there is a way to set up VS to match the structure of IIS? Thank you for any help.

Comment: As far as i know, it is impossible to set up VS to match the structure of IIS. you can setup hostname to website in local IIS by hosts file, but in vs you can only run in localhost.

Comment: thanks for the helpful response samwu. the answer by @HarshitaSingh-MSFT accomplished what i needed. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug a Visual Studio application that has been deployed on a different computer(App Service, VM, etc.) using [**Visual Studio remote debugger**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019).

There are various methods with which you can do that, and it depends on the Tech stack you are using. Pls visit the link above and follow tutorial as appropriate.

*Place your breakpoints in the Login flow, and you will be able to debug deployed code and find out the issue.*